# F# a function as an argument in a match function

Tags: list, f#, match, discriminator, guard-clause

I have made function that takes a list and a list of lists and returns a new list of lists.

```
let rec calculator list SS =
  match (List.item(0) SS) with
  |[] -> []
  |_ -> match (validate list (List.item(0) SS)) with
        |(validate theCode list) -> List.append [(List.item(0) SS)] (calculator list (SS.[1..])) 
        |_ -> (calculator list (SS.[1..]))
```

validate is a function that returns two tupled ints. example (1,1)

list is a list of four ints

SS is a list of lists with four ints

theCode is a list of four ints

i get the error "The pattern discriminator 'validate' is not defined."

Perhaps this is a silly question but none the less i don't know the answer to it.

Is it not allowed to use a function as an argument in a match expression. Or is it something entirely different going on here?

to the best of my knowledge the two validate functions will return two tupled ints and therefore should be able to match upon that.

Comment: I think you want an active pattern here

Comment: *"validate is a function that returns two tupled ints."* Assuming that the function validates some input, what does it return when the input is valid? What does it return when the input is invalid?

Comment: To get this to compile, replace `|(validate theCode list) ->` with `| x when x = (validate theCode list) ->`. But as @JohnPalmer implied, this is plain ugly – even an `if..else` would be cleaner here.

Comment: it will never return something that is invalid. it will always return something that is valid. the least it will return is (0,0) where i tell it to remove all the elements in the list of lists that wont give the same validate result had it been validated with theCode instead.

Comment: okay så what is the prefered method here? i can't quite grasp how that active pattern is usefull here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is how to get this to compile then you only need a small change – a function call is not itself a pattern, so you need to bind to a value and use a [`when` guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions#guards-on-patterns):

```
let rec calculator list SS =
    match (List.item(0) SS) with
    | [] -> []
    | _  ->
        match (validate list (List.item(0) SS)) with
//        vvvvvvvvvv
        | x when x = (validate theCode list) ->
            List.append [(List.item(0) SS)] (calculator list (SS.[1..]))
        | _ -> (calculator list (SS.[1..]))
```

However, if your question is indeed "*what is the preferred method*", then while that's too subjective for this site (IMO), I'll submit this as an option that I consider ideally readable for this logic:

```
let rec calculator list (h::t) =
    if List.isEmpty h then h
    elif validate list h = validate theCode list then h::(calculator list t)
    else calculator list t
```

<sup>(This assumes that `SS` is an F# list and not a `System.Collections.Generic.List`.)</sup>

Comment: Just a note: it would be a little more usual to have `h :: calculator list t` for prepending a single element to a list than constructing a new list of one element just to append a list.

Comment: @JakeLishman : Indeed! I was focused on switching away from `match` and didn't think through the rest thoroughly (apparently). Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is not actually an answer to the question of how to implement the `when` guard, since @ildjarn [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607008/f-a-function-as-an-argument-in-a-match-function/40607693#40607693) that for you.

I think you'd actually be better served by a library function.  What you're trying to do appears to be to filter out elements which don't pass validation, but also to stop on the first empty element.  If you can guarantee that you definitely want to loop through every element of `SS`, you could simply do

```
let calculator list = List.filter (fun s -> validate list s = validate theCode list)
```

If it's you must stop at the empty element, you could define a function that cuts the list at the first empty element, something like

```
let upToElement element list =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | h :: t when h = element -> List.rev acc
        | h :: t -> loop (h :: acc) t
    loop [] list
```

then you can do

```
let calculator list =
    upToElement [] >> List.filter (fun s -> validate list s = validate theCode list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My intend is just to filter out any element that dont pass validation. So I will definitely look into to your List.filter solution!